# If statements not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I am developing an app where the user receives an overall score and are judged from that score and given a title. However, with the code I am using, the end result is always the same, no matter what score the subject gets. I dont know if this a math problem or a code problem, as it always comes up with the first option: You have no SWAG whatsoever...

```
if (totalScore<24) {
    describe.text = @"You have no SWAG whatsoever...";
}

else if (25<totalScore<49) {
    describe.text = @"You seem to be new to SWAG.";
}

 else  if (50<totalScore<74) {
    describe.text = @"You have a bit of SWAG, not enough though.";
}

else    if (75<totalScore<99) {
    describe.text = @"You definately have SWAG!";
}

 else   if (totalScore == 100) {
    describe.text = @"You are a GOD of SWAG.";
}
```

Comment: Output `totalScore` right before this `if` statement and see if it has the value you think it does.

Comment: I have done this with NSLog, and it comes up with the right number. I think it might be a problem with the if statement

Comment: @RafeeJ it _is_ a problem with your if statements. See Barmar's answer.

Comment: @mah having a gander now.

Comment: I'm quite confident your `if` statement is working exactly as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else if (25<totalScore<49) {
```

should be:

```
else if (25<totalScore && totalScore<49) {
```

The way you wrote it is parsed as if you'd written:

```
else if ((25<totalScore) < 49) {
```

`25<totalScore` will be either 1 or 0 depending on whether it's true or false. Either way, it's less than 49.

Also, all your comparisons should be `<=` rather than `<`. Otherwise, you're excluding all the boundary values.

Comment: Yeah, I had originally implemented that, but I thought that was the problem so I deleted them. Thanks for showing me a further insight though! :)

Answer (score 0):

building if in this way

```
if (25<totalScore<49) {...}
```

is risky.In reality you do something like

```
25<totalScore -> YES/NO (values will be casted from BOOL to int as 1/0)
```

and then you will do

```
0/1 < 49 which will be always true.
```

so in total your if is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Your first line of code looks right from what you have displayed so far? You need to output what total score is. You are maybe not setting it before running your code?

Failing that, are you sure its compiling properly? You need to use && in your subsequent if statements.

Also, you need to use <=, because at the moment, if the score is 24 it wont work.

Comment: Andy, the statement `if (25<totalScore<49)` (and its kin) looks right to you?